# How do I create columns which count another column with certain conditions? R

Tags: r, dplyr

Below, the data has already been reshaped, and the inputs and expected output are listed.

**Data**

```
structure(list(record_id = c(110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 
110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 
110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 
110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 
110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 
110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 
110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 
110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101
), start = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 
31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 
47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59), stop = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60), `treatment (type)` = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 
0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), n_interruption_periods = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), n_interruption_periods_3days = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), n_interruption_days_3days = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7)), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Explanation**

*Input*
`start` and `stop` are the day-count. The daily treatment is listed in `treatment`, with 0 = no treatment, which is an interruption, and 1:3 are treatment A/B/C.

*Output*
Based on the `treatment` column, I want to count per day:

1. `n_interruption_periods`: the sum/number of interruption periods, irrespective of the duration of the interruption
2. `n_interruption_periods_3days`: sum/the number of interruptions, with a condition that you should only count when the duration was >= 3 days. Interruptions shorter than 3 day are not of interest
3. `n_interruption_days_3days`: the cumulative sum/number of interruption days, where interruptions are only counted from day 3 of the interruption and on.

**Question**
I want to create a script which calculates these abovementioned output variables automatically based on the `treatment` variable.

Hope you can help

BW

**Response OP**

Here is a part of the data which illustrate the problem:

```
structure(list(record_id = c(110001, 110002, 110002, 110002, 
110001), day_count = c(732, 0, 1, 2, 733), day_count_stop = c(733, 
1, 2, 3, 734), oac_class = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1), n_interruption_periods = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 1), n_interruption_periods_3days = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), groups = structure(list(record_id = c(110001, 110002), 
    .rows = structure(list(c(1L, 5L), 2:4), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

With the suggested code, there are two issues:

1. I believe the resultant vector was not assigned to the correct position. Here you can see that 110002 first data on `n_interruption_periods` and `n_interruption_periods_3days` are extended from 110001 results.
2. When I try to run the third vector, I receive this error:
   Error in while (any(d != 0)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

BW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can modify the function I wrote in your last [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64626161/10802499) to solve all your problems. Consider the following function.

```
conditional_count <- function(x, n, pfill = function(p0) integer(length(p0)), ifill = seq_along, iend = 30L) {
  len <- length(x); out <- integer(len)
  p0 <- which(x == 0L)
  if (n > 1L)
    p0 <- Reduce(function(idx, i) {
      lidx <- idx - i + 1L
      idx <- idx[lidx > 0L]; lidx <- lidx[lidx > 0L]
      idx[x[lidx] == 0L]
    }, seq_len(n)[-1L], p0)
  if (length(p0) < 1L)
    return(out)
  ub <- pmin(c(tail(p0, -1L), len), p0 + iend - 1L)
  rl <- ub - p0 + 1L
  pfill <- pfill(p0)
  res <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(rl), function(i) ifill(integer(rl[[i]])) + pfill[[i]]))
  pos <- inverse.rle(list(lengths = rl, values = p0)) + unlist(lapply(rl, seq_len)) - 1L
  `[<-`(out, pos, res)
}
```

Let p0 be the vector that contains the positions of all valid interruptions identified. `pfill` and `ifill` are two control functions for `conditional_count`. `pfill` controls how to fill in each position in the vector p0; `ifill` controls how to fill in the gap between two valid interruptions. The final sequence in-between two valid interruptions will be `ifill + pfill`. `iend` controls the desired length of the final sequence. See below the illustration (x is treatment (type))

```
ifill controls the numbers  at *:             *****   *****   (iend = 5L for example)
pfill controls the numbers  at ?:             ?       ?
p0 identifies                   :             v       v
x looks like                    :   1    2    0  ...  0  ...
```

Using n = 1 as an example, your last problem simplifies to

```
conditional_count(x, 1L, function(p0) integer(length(p0)), seq_along, 30L)

ifill + pfill                              :       1 2 3 4 ...  1 2 3 4 ...
ifill is a sequence along the gap positions:       1 2 3 4 ...  1 2 3 4 ...
pfill is always 0 at all positions of p0   :       0            0       
p0 identifies                              :       v            v       
x looks like                               :   1 2 0 ........   0
```

This problem simplifies to

```
conditional_count(x, 1L, function(p0) cumsum(p0 - head(c(-1L, p0), -1L) > 1L), function(x) integer(length(x)), Inf)

ifill + pfill                                  :       1 1 1 ...     2 2 ...
ifill is always 0 along the gap positions      :       0 0 0 ...     0 0 ...  (iend = Inf means filling in a sequence until the end of the gap)
pfill increases 1 at each starting streak of 0s:       1             2
p0 identifies                                  :       v v v         v v
x looks like                                   :   1 2 0 0 0 ....... 0 0 ...

conditional_count(x, 1L, seq_along, function(x) integer(length(x)), Inf)

ifill + pfill                            :       1 2 3 ...     4 5 ...
ifill is always 0 along the gap positions:       0 0 0 ...     0 0 ...  (iend = Inf means filling in a sequence until the end of the gap)
pfill increases 1 at each 0              :       1 2 3         4 5
p0 identifies                            :       v v v         v v
x looks like                             :   1 2 0 0 0 ....... 0 0 ...
```

The full script for this problem is

```
conditional_count <- function(x, n, pfill = function(p0) integer(length(p0)), ifill = seq_along, iend = 30L) {
  len <- length(x); out <- integer(len)
  p0 <- which(x == 0L)
  if (n > 1L)
    p0 <- Reduce(function(idx, i) {
      lidx <- idx - i + 1L
      idx <- idx[lidx > 0L]; lidx <- lidx[lidx > 0L]
      idx[x[lidx] == 0L]
    }, seq_len(n)[-1L], p0)
  if (length(p0) < 1L)
    return(out)
  ub <- pmin(c(tail(p0, -1L), len), p0 + iend - 1L)
  rl <- ub - p0 + 1L
  pfill <- pfill(p0)
  res <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(rl), function(i) ifill(integer(rl[[i]])) + pfill[[i]]))
  pos <- inverse.rle(list(lengths = rl, values = p0)) + unlist(lapply(rl, seq_len)) - 1L
  `[<-`(out, pos, res)
}

count_streak <- function(p0) cumsum(p0 - head(c(-1L, p0), -1L) > 1L)
integer_along <- function(x) integer(length(x))

df %>%
  mutate(
    n_interruption_periods = conditional_count(`treatment (type)`, 1L, count_streak, integer_along, Inf),
    n_interruption_periods_3days = conditional_count(`treatment (type)`, 3L, count_streak, integer_along, Inf),
    n_interruption_days_3days = conditional_count(`treatment (type)`, 3L, seq_along, integer_along, Inf)
  )
```

Output

```
   record_id start stop treatment (type) n_interruption_periods n_interruption_periods_3days n_interruption_days_3days
1     110101     0    1                1                      0                            0                         0
2     110101     1    2                1                      0                            0                         0
3     110101     2    3                1                      0                            0                         0
4     110101     3    4                0                      1                            0                         0
5     110101     4    5                0                      1                            0                         0
6     110101     5    6                0                      1                            1                         1
7     110101     6    7                0                      1                            1                         2
8     110101     7    8                2                      1                            1                         2
9     110101     8    9                2                      1                            1                         2
10    110101     9   10                2                      1                            1                         2
11    110101    10   11                0                      2                            1                         2
12    110101    11   12                0                      2                            1                         2
13    110101    12   13                0                      2                            2                         3
14    110101    13   14                0                      2                            2                         4
15    110101    14   15                0                      2                            2                         5
16    110101    15   16                0                      2                            2                         6
17    110101    16   17                3                      2                            2                         6
18    110101    17   18                3                      2                            2                         6
19    110101    18   19                0                      3                            2                         6
20    110101    19   20                3                      3                            2                         6
21    110101    20   21                3                      3                            2                         6
22    110101    21   22                3                      3                            2                         6
23    110101    22   23                0                      4                            2                         6
24    110101    23   24                2                      4                            2                         6
25    110101    24   25                2                      4                            2                         6
26    110101    25   26                2                      4                            2                         6
27    110101    26   27                0                      5                            2                         6
28    110101    27   28                0                      5                            2                         6
29    110101    28   29                0                      5                            3                         7
30    110101    29   30                1                      5                            3                         7
31    110101    30   31                1                      5                            3                         7
32    110101    31   32                1                      5                            3                         7
33    110101    32   33                1                      5                            3                         7
34    110101    33   34                1                      5                            3                         7
35    110101    34   35                1                      5                            3                         7
36    110101    35   36                1                      5                            3                         7
37    110101    36   37                1                      5                            3                         7
38    110101    37   38                1                      5                            3                         7
39    110101    38   39                1                      5                            3                         7
40    110101    39   40                1                      5                            3                         7
41    110101    40   41                1                      5                            3                         7
42    110101    41   42                1                      5                            3                         7
43    110101    42   43                1                      5                            3                         7
44    110101    43   44                1                      5                            3                         7
45    110101    44   45                1                      5                            3                         7
46    110101    45   46                1                      5                            3                         7
47    110101    46   47                1                      5                            3                         7
48    110101    47   48                1                      5                            3                         7
49    110101    48   49                1                      5                            3                         7
50    110101    49   50                1                      5                            3                         7
51    110101    50   51                1                      5                            3                         7
52    110101    51   52                1                      5                            3                         7
53    110101    52   53                1                      5                            3                         7
54    110101    53   54                1                      5                            3                         7
55    110101    54   55                1                      5                            3                         7
56    110101    55   56                1                      5                            3                         7
57    110101    56   57                1                      5                            3                         7
58    110101    57   58                1                      5                            3                         7
59    110101    58   59                1                      5                            3                         7
60    110101    59   60                1                      5                            3                         7
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Completely deleted everything and started over.

I really hope for your sake someone comes up with a less messy answer, but these functions should work.

```
FindFirstVector = function(TreatmentVector){
  #Which entries are equal to 0
  id = which(TreatmentVector == 0)
  #IDs of first zeros occuring (First day w.o. treatment)
  id1 = id[c(0,diff(id)) != 1]
  #Create vector of zeroes
  temp = rep(0,length(TreatmentVector))
  #Add 1 for the first zero
  temp[id1] = 1
  #Take cumulative sum
  cumsum(temp)
}


FindSecondVector = function(TreatmentVector){
  #Which entries are equal to 0
  id = which(TreatmentVector == 0)
  #IDs of first zeros occuring (First day w.o. treatment)
  id1 = id[c(0,diff(id)) != 1]
  #IDs of last zeros (Last day w.o. treatment)
  id2 = id[c(diff(id),2) > 1]
  #Amount of days w.o. treatment is then:
  d = id2 - id1 + 1
  #id3 is then the starting id of period of no treatment, if the period is longer
  #than 2 days. Then 2 is added, so start counting from day 3 of the period.
  id3 = id1[id2 - id1 + 1 > 2] + 2
  temp = rep(0,length(TreatmentVector))
  temp[id3] = 1
  cumsum(temp)
}


# Building third vector ---------------------------------------------------
FindThirdVector = function(TreatmentVector){
  #Which entries are equal to 0
  id = which(TreatmentVector == 0)
  #IDs of first zeros occuring (First day w.o. treatment)
  id1 = id[c(0,diff(id)) != 1]
  #IDs of last zeros (Last day w.o. treatment)
  id2 = id[c(diff(id),2) > 1]
  #Amount of days w.o. treatment is then:
  d = id2 - id1 + 1
  #id3 is then the starting id of period of no treatment, if the period is longer
  #than 2 days. Then 2 is added, so start counting from day 3 of the period.
  id3 = id1[id2 - id1 + 1 > 2] + 2
  #The id of the ending day of period w.o. treatment longer than 2 days.
  id4 = id2[id2 - id1 + 1 > 2]
  
  #d is the amount of days to add 1's
  d = id4-id3
  temp = rep(0,length(TreatmentVector))
  while(any(d!=0)){
    temp[id3 + d] = 1
    d = d - 1
    d[d<0] = 0
  }
  temp[id3 + d] = 1
  cumsum(temp)
}
```

Then you should find your three vectors by running:

```
FindFirstVector(dat$`treatment (type)`)
FindSecondVector(dat$`treatment (type)`)
FindThirdVector(dat$`treatment (type)`)
```

Comment: Thank you, to test whether this worked, i tried ```dat$test <- cumsum(diff(dat$`treatment (type)`)<0)```, which gave the following error

Error: Assigned data `cumsum(diff(so_interruption_df$\`treatment (type)\`) < 0)` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 60 rows.
x Assigned data has 59 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.

I believe this means it only calculates the cumsum from row 2 or day 1, thus not giving an output for the first day (day 0-1). See comment below

Comment: cumsum(diff(so_interruption_df$`treatment (type)`)<0)
 [1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5

It misses a 0 at the beginning

Comment: Oh, right sorry. I remembered it as if ```diff()``` always starts with a 0. It is a function which output the differences between entries in a vector. 
This will also cause problems, if the first entry in your ```treatment``` is a 0, so this method is by second thought not recommendable.

Comment: I'll update or delete my answer during the evening, depending on whether I come up with a solution :-)

Comment: @KBChu I've updated my answer. It however got a lot longer than I thought it would. Even using base R it can almost certainly be shortened.

Comment: This worked indeed! Fantastic and thank you. Especially for the explanations per line. Still need some time to understand it. One follow-up question: If I would want to use your functions for multiple records as I have other persons in the database,  what should I do? Do I need to mix a group_by function into this?

Comment: @KBChu I guess the different persons are defined by their Id? In that case something like: ```n_interruption_periods = unname(unlist(tapply(dat$`treatment (type)`, 
                                       dat$record_id, FindFirstVector)))``` should work. ```tapply``` will in this case output a list of named vectors, one for each Id. Hence the ```unlist``` and ```unname```.
If parts of the code is under-explained, please feel free to ask, what they do.

Comment: I found an example of an error in the output: 

110001 732 733 0 0 1
110002 0 1 3 1 1

Comment: It's hard for me to know what goes wrong, since I don't have acces to the full data. But you could try using the ```debug()``` function to see, where things go wrong.

Comment: Absolutely, I gave a horrendous example. Will try to see if I could do a dput soon. Thanks for all the work you have done. BW

Comment: Hereabove is a dput of an example error and a short assessment @Qwethm

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter (and in my opinion, cleaner) solution using `dplyr`. I'm not sure about the error you got with the other solution, but maybe this works better for you.

```r
# Group by record_id
data = data %>% group_by(record_id)

# Define helper column
count_streak = function(v) accumulate(v, ~if_else(.y, .x + 1, 0), .init = 0)[-1]
data = data %>% mutate(interruption_streak = count_streak(`treatment (type)` == 0))

data = data %>%
  mutate(n_interruption_periods = cumsum(interruption_streak == 1),
         n_interruption_periods_3days = cumsum(interruption_streak == 3),
         n_interruption_days_3days = cumsum(interruption_streak >= 3))
```

We define a helper column `interruption_streak` that counts up with each day of the current interruption period. So on the first day of every interruption period, it is `1`, and so on.

From this, we can calculate the other columns:

- `n_interruption_periods` is simply the cumulative count of days where an interruption period begins.
- `n_interruption_periods_3days` is the cumulative count of third days of interruption periods.
- `n_interruption_days_3days` is the cumulative count of days that are the *third day or higher* of an interruption period.

I hope this explanation made sense, otherwise feel free to ask.