# R - starting and resetting a counting column in R based on condition

Tags: r, dplyr, counting

I would like to thank for all the help already in advance, as the help until now has allowed me go get new ideas/hypotheses on how my data could be analysed.

**Data**

```
structure(list(record_id = c(110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 
110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 
110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 
110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 
110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 
110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 
110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 
110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101, 110101
), start = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 
31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 
47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59), stop = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60), `treatment (type)` = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 
0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), vulnerable_period_30count = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
30, 0, 0), vulnerable_period_yn = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), vulnerable_period_30count_3days = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 0, 0), vulnerable_period_3days_yn = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -60L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Explanation**

*Input*
`start` and `stop` are the day-count. The daily treatment is listed in `treatment`, with 0 = no treatment, which is an interruption, and 1:3 are treatment A/B/C.

The hypothesis is that once a person has had a treatment interruption, he or she is vulnerable for the next 30 days.

So based on these inputs I would like to count/calculate the following outputs:

*Output*

`vulnerable_period_30count`: when a treatment interruption occurs (treatment (type) = 0), it start counting to 30. It automatically resets when a treatment interruption occurs.

`vulnerable_period_30count_3days`: only if a treatment interruption lasts for three days (thus three consecutive 0's) or longer, is the interruption relevant. Then, it will start counting to 30.
If the interruption last longer than the three days, it will reset the count again. NOTE: see day 6, the interruption lasts 4 days in total. The count resets when the 4 day interruption ended.

When the count has exceeded 30, it reverts back to 0 and will only start counting when a relevant interruption occurred again.

Here the attempt for the vulnerable_period_30count.

**Attempt for vulnerable_period_30count**

```
data$vulnerable_period_30count <- data %>% 
  group_by(record_id, idx = cumsum(`treatment (type)` == 0L)) %>% 
  mutate(counter = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-idx)
data$test[data$test >30] <- 0
```

The problem here that it start with 1, 2, 3 already. I hard-stop the count with the last line.

For how to only start count when three or more interruptions occured, i have absolutely no idea.

Hope you can help

BW

**Comment OP on Answer 2**
@Ekoam Thanks again. The code now runs which is good. Two errors I managed to find. I will use one case to illustrate:

```
structure(list(record_id = c(110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003), day_count = c(0, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 
68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 
84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 
100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 
113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 
126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 
139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 
152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 
165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 
178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 
191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 
204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 
217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 
230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 
243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 
256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 
269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 
282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 
295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 
308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 
321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 
334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 
347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 
360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 
373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 
386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 
399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 
412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 
425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 
438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 
451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 
464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472), day_count_stop = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 
68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 
84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 
100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 
113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 
126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 
139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 
152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 
165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 
178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 
191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 
204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 
217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 
230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 
243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 
256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 
269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 
282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 
295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 
308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 
321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 
334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 
347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 
360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 
373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 
386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 
399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 
412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 
425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 
438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 
451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 
464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473), oac_class = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), vulnerable_period_30count = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 
76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 
89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 
112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 
123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 
134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 
145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 
156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 
167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 
178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 
189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 
200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 
211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 
222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 
233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 
244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 
255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 
266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 
277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 
288L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 
299L, 300L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 308L, 309L, 
310L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 
321L, 322L, 323L, 324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 330L, 331L, 
332L, 333L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 338L, 339L, 340L, 341L, 342L, 
343L, 344L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 351L, 352L, 353L, 
354L, 355L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 360L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 
365L, 366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 370L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 
376L, 377L, 378L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 382L, 383L, 384L, 385L, 386L, 
387L, 388L, 389L, 390L, 391L, 392L, 393L, 394L, 395L, 396L, 397L, 
398L, 399L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 406L, 407L, 408L, 
409L, 410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 418L, 419L, 
420L, 421L, 422L, 423L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 429L, 430L, 
431L, 432L, 433L, 434L, 1L), vulnerable_period_30count_3days = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 
64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 
77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 
90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 
102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 
113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 
124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 
135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 
146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 
157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 
168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 
179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 
190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 
201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 
212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 
223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 
234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 
245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 
256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 
267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 
278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 
289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 
300L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 
311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 321L, 
322L, 323L, 324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 330L, 331L, 332L, 
333L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 338L, 339L, 340L, 341L, 342L, 343L, 
344L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 351L, 352L, 353L, 354L, 
355L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 360L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 365L, 
366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 370L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 376L, 
377L, 378L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 382L, 383L, 384L, 385L, 386L, 387L, 
388L, 389L, 390L, 391L, 392L, 393L, 394L, 395L, 396L, 397L, 398L, 
399L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 406L, 407L, 408L, 409L, 
410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 418L, 419L, 420L, 
421L, 422L, 423L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 429L, 430L, 431L, 
432L, 433L, 434L, 435L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -473L), groups = structure(list(
    record_id = 110003, .rows = structure(list(1:473), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

1. At day 66 or day 67 the day count does not stop, and continues counting. This occurs for several other record_id's as wlel.
2. At day 36 and 38, the vulnerable_day_30_count starts counting too soon.
3. At the final day, the vulnerable_day_30_count start counting already, although there has not been an interruption of 3 days.

Comment: Plesae show the code for your best attempt.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck - see above for the rolling 30 day count attempt. For the interruption count with the 3 day criteria, I have absolutely no idea (yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a function like this:

```
# 1. Determine the positions of zeros (p0) in `x`.
# 2. Test whether p0 - 1, p0 - 2, ..., p0 - n + 1 are zeros; 
#    reduce p0 to those that satisfy all conditions.
# 3. Find the upper bounds (ub). For example, if p0 = c(1,2,3), 
#    then upper bounds will be c(2,3,?) (i.e. lead p0). 
#    ? is then 3 + 30 (the max you set) if it is still within 
#    the length of `x`; otherwise is the length of `x` plus 1.
# 4. Compute the sequence between each pair of p0 and ub and 
#    then unlist the result to a vector.
# 5. Assign the vector back to its correct position.

conditional_count <- function(x, n, max = 30L) {
  len <- length(x); out <- integer(len)
  p0 <- which(x == 0L)
  if (n > 1L)
    p0 <- Reduce(function(idx, i)  idx[x[(idx - i + 1L)] == 0L], seq_len(n)[-1L], p0)
  ub <- c(tail(p0, -1L), min(len + 1L, tail(p0, 1L) + max))
  res <- unlist(lapply(ub - p0, seq_len))
  `[<-`(out, p0[[1L]] + seq.int(0L, length(res) - 1L), res)
}
```

Then you can just

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    vulnerable_period_30count = conditional_count(`treatment (type)`, 1L), 
    vulnerable_period_30count_3days = conditional_count(`treatment (type)`, 3L)
  )
```

Output (the `df` I used only has four variables: `record_id`, `start`, `stop`, `treatment (type)`. Other variables were removed.)

```
   record_id start stop treatment (type) vulnerable_period_30count vulnerable_period_30count_3days
1     110101     0    1                1                         0                               0
2     110101     1    2                1                         0                               0
3     110101     2    3                1                         0                               0
4     110101     3    4                0                         1                               0
5     110101     4    5                0                         1                               0
6     110101     5    6                0                         1                               1
7     110101     6    7                0                         1                               1
8     110101     7    8                2                         2                               2
9     110101     8    9                2                         3                               3
10    110101     9   10                2                         4                               4
11    110101    10   11                0                         1                               5
12    110101    11   12                0                         1                               6
13    110101    12   13                0                         1                               1
14    110101    13   14                0                         1                               1
15    110101    14   15                0                         1                               1
16    110101    15   16                0                         1                               1
17    110101    16   17                3                         2                               2
18    110101    17   18                3                         3                               3
19    110101    18   19                0                         1                               4
20    110101    19   20                3                         2                               5
21    110101    20   21                3                         3                               6
22    110101    21   22                3                         4                               7
23    110101    22   23                0                         1                               8
24    110101    23   24                2                         2                               9
25    110101    24   25                2                         3                              10
26    110101    25   26                2                         4                              11
27    110101    26   27                0                         1                              12
28    110101    27   28                0                         1                              13
29    110101    28   29                0                         1                               1
30    110101    29   30                1                         2                               2
31    110101    30   31                1                         3                               3
32    110101    31   32                1                         4                               4
33    110101    32   33                1                         5                               5
34    110101    33   34                1                         6                               6
35    110101    34   35                1                         7                               7
36    110101    35   36                1                         8                               8
37    110101    36   37                1                         9                               9
38    110101    37   38                1                        10                              10
39    110101    38   39                1                        11                              11
40    110101    39   40                1                        12                              12
41    110101    40   41                1                        13                              13
42    110101    41   42                1                        14                              14
43    110101    42   43                1                        15                              15
44    110101    43   44                1                        16                              16
45    110101    44   45                1                        17                              17
46    110101    45   46                1                        18                              18
47    110101    46   47                1                        19                              19
48    110101    47   48                1                        20                              20
49    110101    48   49                1                        21                              21
50    110101    49   50                1                        22                              22
51    110101    50   51                1                        23                              23
52    110101    51   52                1                        24                              24
53    110101    52   53                1                        25                              25
54    110101    53   54                1                        26                              26
55    110101    54   55                1                        27                              27
56    110101    55   56                1                        28                              28
57    110101    56   57                1                        29                              29
58    110101    57   58                1                        30                              30
59    110101    58   59                1                         0                               0
60    110101    59   60                1                         0                               0
```

**Update**

```
conditional_count <- function(x, n, max = 30L) {
  len <- length(x); out <- integer(len)
  p0 <- which(x == 0L)
  if (n > 1L)
    p0 <- Reduce(function(idx, i)  idx[x[(idx - i + 1L)] == 0L], seq_len(n)[-1L], p0)
  if (length(p0) < 1L)
    return(out)
  ub <- c(tail(p0, -1L), min(len + 1L, tail(p0, 1L) + max))
  res <- unlist(lapply(ub - p0, seq_len))
  `[<-`(out, p0[[1L]] + seq.int(0L, length(res) - 1L), res)
}
```

This error is likely due to no such zero satisfying your conditions stated above. Hence, p0 is of length 0. We can add one more if-else statement to handle this boundary condition. Try with the code shown above. If it's still not working, please consider updating your problem with something like `dput(df[record_id == *, ])`, where `*` represents the erratic group (i.e. 110005 in this case).

**Update 2**

```
conditional_count <- function(x, n, max = 30L) {
  len <- length(x); out <- integer(len)
  p0 <- which(x == 0L)
  if (n > 1L)
    p0 <- Reduce(function(idx, i) {
      lidx <- idx - i + 1L; lidx <- lidx[lidx > 0L]
      idx[x[lidx] == 0L]
    }, seq_len(n)[-1L], p0)
  if (length(p0) < 1L)
    return(out)
  ub <- c(tail(p0, -1L), min(len + 1L, tail(p0, 1L) + max))
  res <- unlist(lapply(ub - p0, seq_len))
  `[<-`(out, p0[[1L]] + seq.int(0L, length(res) - 1L), res)
}
```

I managed to reproduce your problem using some simulated data. The error is also caused by a boundary condition. When the code tries to verify the sequence p0 - 1, p0 - 2, ..., it may go into negative if there is a zero at the beginning of the vector `treatment (type)`. I have corrected that part. Try with the updated code above.

#### Update 3

```
conditional_count <- function(x, n, max = 30L) {
  len <- length(x); out <- integer(len)
  p0 <- which(x == 0L)
  if (n > 1L)
    p0 <- Reduce(function(idx, i) {
      lidx <- idx - i + 1L
      idx <- idx[lidx > 0L]; lidx <- lidx[lidx > 0L]
      idx[x[lidx] == 0L]
    }, seq_len(n)[-1L], p0)
  if (length(p0) < 1L)
    return(out)
  ub <- pmin(c(tail(p0, -1L), len), p0 + max - 1L)
  rl <- ub - p0 + 1L
  res <- unlist(lapply(rl, seq_len))
  pos <- inverse.rle(list(lengths = rl, values = p0)) + res - 1L
  `[<-`(out, pos, res)
}
```

Try with this new one. I reworked some logics. I previously assumed that only the count for the last valid zero can go beyond 30 days. That's why the count never stops for in-between valid zeros. Furthermore, the resultant vector was not assigned to the correct position. This bug also creates some anomalies you have observed. I have corrected both. The result now looks like this

```
structure(list(record_id = c(110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 
110003, 110003, 110003, 110003, 110003), day_count = c(0, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 
68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 
84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 
100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 
113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 
126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 
139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 
152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 
165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 
178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 
191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 
204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 
217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 
230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 
243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 
256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 
269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 
282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 
295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 
308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 
321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 
334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 
347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 
360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 
373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 
386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 
399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 
412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 
425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 
438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 
451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 
464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472), day_count_stop = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 
68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 
84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 
100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 
113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 
126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 
139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 
152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 
165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 
178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 
191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 
204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 
217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 
230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 
243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 
256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 
269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 
282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 
295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 
308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 
321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 
334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 
347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 
360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 
373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 
386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 
399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 
412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 
425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 
438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 
451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 
464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473), oac_class = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), vulnerable_period_30count = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), vulnerable_period_30count_3days = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-473L), groups = structure(list(record_id = 110003, .rows = structure(list(
    1:473), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! With the example provided hereabove, the code works absolutely fine. 

However, in a larger dataset, I receive this error... 
```Error: Problem with mutate() input vulnerable_period_30count. x subscript out of bounds ℹ Input vulnerable_period_30count is conditional_count(oac, 1L). ℹ The error occurred in group 5: record_id = 110005. Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred.```

The larger dataset has around 480000 observations. Would this be too much?

Comment: Hi @ekoam, I tried the following with your code:
```
test_oac_ev_daily <- oac_ev_daily %>% 
  group_by(record_id) %>%
  mutate(
    vulnerable_period_30count = conditional_count(oac_class, 1L), 
    vulnerable_period_30count_3days = conditional_count(oac_class, 3L)
  )```

With: ``` class(oac_ev_daily$oac_class) ``` = [1] "numeric". Ranging from 0-3.

Comment: and this was the error:

 Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `vulnerable_period_30count_3days`.
x only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
ℹ Input `vulnerable_period_30count_3days` is `conditional_count(oac_class, 3L)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: record_id = 110001.

Does this clarify a bit more?

If this does not suffice, I will attempt to give a dput of 110001 or 110005. However, the list is quite extensive (730 observations). We will see whether it fit.

otherwise, is there a possibility for e-mail if it does not fit?

Comment: Hi @ekoam. Thank you very much The code now works fine. This is way above my R knowledge. If you have time and the interest to tackle a similar problem, I would like to invite you to take a look at this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64612360/how-do-i-create-columns-which-count-another-column-with-certain-conditions-r/64612679?noredirect=1#comment114297778_64612679 BW KB

Comment: That post already has an accepted answer. What else do you expect? @KBChu

Comment: Oh I see. I unchecked the answer, as in the larger set, it produced errors. I have clarified the problem and possible errors with data output. Sincerely, I mean no rush or force, only when you have time and are interested as it partially overlaps with this problem, which you have solved.

Comment: Hi @KBChu, I have answered that problem. You can check now.